# parsing element with attribute value in apostrophe

Tags: php, parsing, xpath

I'm trying to parse every first children of "tr" elements, which have "onmouseover" attribute with some value. Html is written using following syntax:

```
<tr onmouseover="change_style(this, '#d0e2d0');">
```

So I wrote this, what does not work:

```
//tr[@onmouseover='change_style(this, '#d0e2d0');']/td[1]
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you show us the HTML markup?

Comment: i've corrected, thanks

Comment: I'm no xpath expert, but you probably shouldn't be using single quotes inside that single-quoted expression without at least escaping them.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sammitch realized, you're having some problems with your quotes; otherwise the expression seems to be fine. Easiest way would be to replace the outer quotes with double quotes:

```
//tr[@onmouseover="change_style(this, '#d0e2d0');"]/td[1]
```

You will have to escape one of the two quote pairs, depending on what quotes you use in PHP.

If this still does not help, make sure there is no difference in whitespace, and try using `contains(@onmouseover, "change_style(this, '#d0e2d0');")` inside the predicate.